# How do I generate jsonschema from java with descriptions, ideally using type javadoc

Tags: java, json, generator, jsonschema

I am generating jsonschema from java using the jackson classes:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonSchema jsonSchema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(Sample.class);
ObjectNode node = jsonSchema.getSchemaNode();
ObjectWriter or = mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter();
or.writeValue(System.out, node);
```

This works fine, but I was wondering how I might get descriptions added, e.g. from the type javadoc.

Comment: I believe with jackson 2.2 there is now a jsonschema module that implements a visitor pattern that should allow you to then process the javadoc. However, I would also like to know how to do this in jackson 1.x. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema